# Custom directive : unable to access directive scope in controller scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to access `$http` inside my controller to read from `JSON` data, where Filename is retrieved from  custom  directive attribute.

here is my code

```
.directive("myCarousel", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',

        scope: {
            jsondatasource: '='
        },

        controller: "carouselCtrl",
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            $scope.jsondatasource = attrs.jsondatasource;

        },

        template: 'mytemplate.html'

    }
})

.controller('carouselCtrl', function ($scope,  $http) {

    $scope.quotes = "";
    $http.get($scope.jsondatasource).success(function (data) { 
        $scope.quotes = data;   
    });

    // some function with operation on the data on quotes received by JSON data

})
```

and HTML call

```
<my-carousel jsondatasource="data.json"> </my-carousel>
```

Comment: Directive with private scope (jsondatasource) should be accessible in controllers scope. Link function in this scenario is additional code. Please let us know what is your real issue that needs to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

What is your problem exactly ?

You defined a scope for your directive, so your link function is useless because angular put to $scope.jsondatasource the evaluation of jsondatasource attribute.

Comment: as I want to access the attribute value  of jsondatasource defined in (html)  inside controller to retrieve data from json where value contain the name of json file. Link function is used to access the attribute value in jsondatasource

Answer (score 0):

try

```
link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    ctrl.jsondatasource = attrs.jsondatasource;
},
```

Comment: not working. as I want to access jsondatasource attribute value   in controller to fetch the data from json.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it might be is to put your http.get into a function inside the controller, attached to scope and taking jsonDataSource as a parameter. And in the link function invoke the function with the jsonSource passed in the directive attribute.

```
.directive("myCarousel", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',

    scope: {
        jsondatasource: '='
    },

    controller: "carouselCtrl",
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.getQuotesData(attrs.jsondatasource);

    },

    template: 'mytemplate.html'

}
})
.controller('carouselCtrl', function ($scope,  $http) {

$scope.quotes = "";
$scope.getQuotesData = function(source) {
  $http.get(source).success(function (data) { 
    $scope.quotes = data;   
  });
};

// some function with operation on the data on quotes received by JSON data

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got another solution instead of '=' in jsondatasource I replaced with '@' and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

use '@' instead of '='
so
jsondatasource: '='

will changed into 
jsondatasource: '@'
will resolve the problem and jsondatasource value is available in controller.